# WPF Datagrid Get Cell Value in MVVM architecture

Tags: wpf, mvvm, datagrid, cell

How to get selected Cell value from Datagrid?

**What information i have looked?**   Everything where title was "WPF get cell value MVVM".

**What i did?** 1 step:

```
    <Page x:Class="PDB.UsersView"
      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
      xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
      xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
      xmlns:local="clr-namespace:PDB"
      xmlns:PDB ="clr-namespace:PDBapi;assembly=PDBapi"
      mc:Ignorable="d" 
      d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800"
      Title="UsersView"
      >

    <Page.DataContext>
        <PDB:UsersViewModel/>
    </Page.DataContext>

    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <!--Page Header info content-->
        <Grid Grid.Row="0">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=myGrd, Path=CurrentCell.Column.DisplayIndex}"/>
        </Grid>
        <!--Datagrid content-->
        <DataGrid x:Name="myGrd" 
                  SelectionMode="Single"
                  SelectionUnit="Cell"
                  IsReadOnly="True"
                  Grid.Row="1" 
                  ItemsSource="{Binding Users}" 
                  AutoGenerateColumns="True"

                  CanUserAddRows="False">
            <DataGrid.InputBindings>
                <MouseBinding MouseAction="RightClick"
                  Command="{Binding CellClickCommand}"
                  CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=myGrd, Path=CurrentCell}" />
            </DataGrid.InputBindings>

        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

VM:

```cs
        public  UsersViewModel()
        {
            UserList = new ObservableCollection<User>();

            GetUsers();

            Users = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(UserList);

            CellClickCommand = new RelayParamCommand((data) => GetValue(data));
        }

        public void GetUsers()
        {
            User user = new User();

            // Users = await user.GetUsers();
            UserList.Add(new User
            {
                Name = "Marius",
                Departament = "some",
                Tabelis = 5
            });

            UserList.Add(
            new User
            {
                Name = "Darius",
                Departament = "unknown",
                Tabelis = 20
            });
        }

        private void GetValue(object data)
        {

            var some = (DataGridCellInfo)data;

            //Returns only number
            Console.WriteLine(some.Column?.DisplayIndex.ToString());
        }
    }
```

But with this approach i faced 2 issues:
In xaml page i added textblock for testing which text was binded to datagrid currentCell. When i click right mouse button it shows int value correctly. But in my GetValue(object data) function console return null at first right click and from second time returns int value, but value in console is always diferent from textblock value, i have to click two times on same cell to get right cell position. That is completly wrong. How to solve that?

Another issue:  How  to get real value from currentCell i have binded?

**What i did?** 2 step:

In xaml  i binded datagrid  currentCell to VM property `CurrentCell="{Binding Cell}"` 
I got value it was ok, but still it returns only  DataGridCellInfo object. I tried to cast to Users object and various things but i failed to get value of cell.
Can someone provide good practice to get cell value from datagrid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data grid is bound to a collection of users, so each user is represented by one row, not one cell. That's why `CurrentCell` returns a `DataGridCellInfo`

If you want the user, bind to `CurrentItem` instead.

In XAML:

```
<DataGrid 
    ItemsSource="{Binding Users}"
    CurrentItem="{Binding SelectedUser}"...
```

In the view model:

```
private user selectedUser;
public user SelectedUser
{
    get => selectedUser;
    set
    {
        var u = value as user;
        selectedUser = u;
    }
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for your replay. But have you tested your solution? It doesn't work.

Comment: I can't try your exact code because it's not comlete. I works in my test program, but I notice that you're using `SelectionUnit="Cell"`, which will need to be removed to use SelectedItem

Comment: Thank you very much. It works :) It was my mistake.

Comment: But if i want to get one cells value i have implement aditional functionality like: switch(cell.position): case 0 return name case 1 return depratament case 2 return another value?

Comment: Yes. but the idea of MVVM is that the ViewModel can work with properties of your user, and doesn't have to think about cells in a grid. The View should be seen as just a way to visualise the data, unlike windows forms, where a complex visual object manipulates the data.